# Filtering Stream depending on document field value

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a Flutter project that gets data from Cloud Firestore.

This is the Stream where I am getting all data:

```
//Get Entries
  Stream<List<Evento>> getEventos(){
    return _db
        .collection('eventos')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => Evento.fromJson(doc.data()))
        .toList());
  }
```

This works fine to fetch all collection items, but there is screen in my project where I need to fetch items that match a field value.

Here you have the structure of a document in the collection 'eventos':

[image]

I need to fetch only the documents which field 'interes' is equal to a specific string, like 'bares' or 'restaurantes'.

How should I change getEventos() to let me filter depending on the value for field 'interes' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use queries with `whereIn` operator:

```dart
Stream<List<Evento>> getEventos(){
  return _db
      .collection('eventos')
      .where('interes', whereIn: ['bares', 'restaurantes'])
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
      .map((doc) => Evento.fromJson(doc.data()))
      .toList());
}
```

This query will return the documents where value of interes is either bares or restaurantes.